# Get categories for current page/entry

Tags: templating, category

For templating, I need to be able to see what the categories of the current entry is. I'm aware of how to get all categories in craft via

```
{% set categories = craft.categories %}
```

however I haven't come across a way to simple get the categories that are set for the entry. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access the categories through the category field itself.

```
{% for category in entry.categoryFieldHandle %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When trying this in _entry.html, I get an internal server error "Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "categoryFieldHandle"."

Comment: 'categoryFieldHandle' is just a placeholder for your category field name (technically called it's 'handle'). You should replace this with your field handle as defined in the field settings.

Answer (score 6):

If might be your wording but I can see two potential answers here.

You either want to list categories set through a category field on the entry, in that case the code Douglas has supplied will work perfectly.

The other answer I can see is you have multiple categories that are assigned to an entry, and you want to list those categories out. If so, this will help:

```
{# Fetch all of the categories related to this entry #}
{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo(entry) %}

{# Output them #}
{% for category in categories %}
    <a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Hopefully myself and Douglas have covered both bases for you here.

Comment: When trying this, I get no output, even when the entry has multiple categories set :-/

Comment: Just for anyone seeing this 7 years later: `craft.categories().relatedTo(entry).all()` or `collect()` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Your entry is tied to the category via the field you have made. You can access the field like every other field.

```
entry.categoryFieldName.one()
```

Will get the first one